# .NET Source-Overriding Default Methods for TextReader.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, .net

In [.NET's TextReader class](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/TextReader.cs,e64583ea204ca037), there are two methods that, by default, simply return -1:

`public virtual int Peek() { return -1; }`

`public virtual int Read() { return -1; }`

I am trying to follow the source code of [Console.ReadLine()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/Console.cs,bc8fd98a32c60ffd); it seems to call Peek() and Read() through [TextReader's ReadLine() method](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/TextReader.cs,91b2c7adbdc4b165).

In regards to the TextReader.ReadLine() method, how are Read() and Peek() overridden such that they can return values other than -1?

Comment: Is this resolved?

Comment: Yes. I think both of the current responses (both Christian.K's and yours) answered the questions I was asking, albeit from different angles. Therefore, I didn't choose either of them as the "correct answer", since I can only select one. I instead opted for upvoting both of your answers.

Comment: But you should accept answer which is more relevant

Answer (score 1):

The Console class initializes its `In` TextWriter [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/Console.cs,58) lazily.

The `ConsolePal.GetOrCreateReader()`, which sets up the reader, is implemented [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/ConsolePal.Unix.cs,99) (for Unix, but Windows would be comparable).

Essentially it [uses](https://source.dot.net/#System.Console/System/ConsolePal.Unix.cs,107) a plain `StreamReader` as backing, which has `Read()` implemented.

Answer (score 1):

`TextReader`  is and abstract class and the `Peek` method is virtual.

```
public abstract partial class TextReader : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable

// This default method simply returns -1.
//
public virtual int Peek()
{
    return -1;
}
```

A class extending this `TextReader` class can implement (overide) the method `Peek` and return other than -1.

[image]